# Long loading/update of achievements (Google Play Games for Unity)

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play-games

When updating incremental achievements the list of achievements is loaded for a long time (~30-60 sec) and unlock achievements not displayed (the achievement successfully unlocked in the achievements list). As if the queue of events is being hammered. Nobody faced? The method of updating the progress of achievements is not called often, specially re-checked.

My code:

```
EventManager.CoinTaken.Subscribe(() =>
{
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(GPGSIds.achievement_collect_100_coins, 1, null);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(GPGSIds.achievement_collect_250_coins, 1, null);
    PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(GPGSIds.achievement_collect_500_coins, 1, null);
});
```

The coin is taken on average once every 10-30 seconds.

I use [play-games-plugin-for-unity](https://github.com/playgameservices/play-games-plugin-for-unity/) plugin for Unity.

Answer (score 0):

Found a tutorial that might be of help [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ae8GeRmdH0). What he did was placed the:

```
PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(id, stepsToIncrement, success => { });
```

inside a function

```
  public static void IncrementAchievement(string id, int stepsToIncrement)
    {
        PlayGamesPlatform.Instance.IncrementAchievement(id, stepsToIncrement, success => { });
    }
```

which would trigger every time he pressed a button. The update was instantaneous. Hope that helps.